# Como posso implementar uma recursividade num método que implementou a iteratividade, tendo as mesmas entradas e o mesmo retorno? O código está em C

Tags: c, array, recursão, iterator

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *concatenarDoisVetores(
    int *vetor1, int vetor1Posicoes, int *vetor2, int vetor2Posicoes)
{
    // uso da iteratividade:
    int *vetor3;
    int vetor2Posicao = 0;

    vetor3 = (int *)malloc((vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes) * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes; i++)
    {
        if (i < vetor1Posicoes)
        {
            vetor3[i] = vetor1[i];
        }
        else
        {
            vetor3[i] = vetor2[vetor2Posicao];
            vetor2Posicao++;
        }
    }
    return vetor3;

    // uso da recursividade:
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    int v1Posicoes = 7, v2Posicoes = 3;
    int v1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int v2[] = {7, 8, 9};
    int *v3;

    v3 = concatenarDoisVetores(v1, v1Posicoes, v2, v2Posicoes);

    for (int i = 0; i < v1Posicoes + v2Posicoes; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", v3[i]);
    }

    free(v3);

    return 0;
}
```

Neste código eu usei a iteratividade para implementar a concatenação de dois vetores. Porém, eu gostaria de saber como posso descartar a iteratividade e implementar a recursividade mantendo a mesma assinatura e o mesmo retorno da função `concatenarDoisVetores`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recursividade apenas troca o loop por uma chamada de função e em alguns casos pode ser interessante ou eficiente, Em outros apenas uma curiosidade.

Vou deixar um exemplo, com o código e a saída, a  seguir.

#### sobre a funçao original

```
int* concatenarDoisVetores(
    int* vetor1, int vetor1Posicoes, int* vetor2,
    int vetor2Posicoes)
{
    int* vetor3;
    int  vetor2Posicao = 0;

    vetor3 = (int*)malloc(
        (vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes) * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes;
         i++)
    {
        if (i < vetor1Posicoes) { vetor3[i] = vetor1[i]; }
        else
        {
            vetor3[i] = vetor2[vetor2Posicao];
            vetor2Posicao++;
        }
    }
    return vetor3;
}
```

- considere que uma vez que tenha copiado o primeiro vetor para a saída o valor de `i` vai ser sempre maior que o de `vetor1Posicoes` e o valor de `i` é sempre incrementado. Assim não é boa idéia testar **TODA VEZ** dentro do loop uma coisa que já aconteceu. `i` só está aumentando e `vetor1Posicoes` é constante. Se isso vale uma nota pode te custar uns pontos. Num emprego pode gerar algum embaraço. Simplesmente repita o loop.
- evite esses nomes gigantes para variáveis que usa toda hora. Só fica difícil de ler.
- em geral declare como `const` parâmetros que são constantes. Pode salvar horas de teste no futuro
- em geral declare como `unsigned` campos de tamanho. É ruim quando alguém manda um valor negativo só pra testar e você não tinha previsto isso.

#### outra opção, iterativa

Compare com essa função, que faz a mesma coisa:

```
int* cnctn2v_i(int* v1, int sz1, int* v2, int sz2)
{
    int* v3 = (int*)malloc((sz1+sz2) * sizeof(int));
    if (v3 == NULL) return v3;
    int* p = v3;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz1; i++) *p++ = v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz2; i++) *p++ = v2[i];
    return v3;
}
```

É bem mais simples de ler e muito mais eficiente, já que não testa durante a cópia do segundo vetor se o primeiro já terminou...

#### o programa de teste

Considere sempre o que já sabe que seu programa vai fazer. É claro que vai ser preciso mostrar os vetores de entrada e a saída de cada teste, então escreva uma função. Considere algo assim:

```
int show_v(int* V, int sz, const char* msg)
{
    if (V == NULL) return -1;
    if (sz <= 0) return 0;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d valor(es): [ ", sz);
    if (sz == 1)
    {
        printf("%d ]\n", V[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) printf("%i, ", V[i]);
    printf("%i ]\n", V[sz - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Que mostra o vetor e aceita um título, eliminando os chatos `printf` espalhados pelo teste

#### main para o teste

```
int main(void)
{   // os vetores
    int v1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int sz1  = sizeof(v1) / sizeof(v1[0]);
    show_v(v1, sz1, "\nVetor 1: ");
    int v2[] = {7, 8, 9};
    int sz2  = sizeof(v2) / sizeof(v2[0]);
    show_v(v2, sz2, "\nVetor 2: ");
    // e os testes
    testa_funcao(
        concatenarDoisVetores, v1, sz1, v2, sz2,
        "\n(iterativa 1) ");
    testa_funcao(
        cnctn2v_r, v1, sz1, v2, sz2, "\n(recursiva) ");
    testa_funcao(
        cnctn2v_i, v1, sz1, v2, sz2, "\n(iterativa 2) ");
    return 0;
}
```

O mínimo: cria e mostra os dois vetores e depois usa uma função para testar as 3 funções em sequência. Mais simples de ler e de usar.

**`testa_funcao`** pode ser simples e minimalista:

```
int testa_funcao(
    int* (*f)(int*, int, int*, int), int* v1, int sz1,
    int* v2, int sz2, const char* msg)
{
    int* v3 = f(v1, sz1, v2, sz2);
    show_v(v3, sz1 + sz2, msg);
    free(v3);
    return 0;
}
```

Como já temos a função que mostra a saída basta chamar a função, mostrar o resultado e apagar o vetor.

#### a saída do programa

```
Vetor 1: 7 valor(es): [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

Vetor 2: 3 valor(es): [ 7, 8, 9 ]

(iterativa 1) 10 valor(es): [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

(recursiva) 10 valor(es): [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

(iterativa 2) 10 valor(es): [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

#### a função recursiva

A função `concatenarDoisVetores` em si poderia ser recursiva, mas não está claro se precisa ser essa a recursão ou se o que busca é uma solução usando recursividade. Para usar essa função apenas teria que separar o código inicial que aloca o vetor de saída, e precisaria testar isso a cada recursão, porque a função seria chamada de novo e a partir da segunda vez não poderia alocar memória.
Se precisa ser uma função só escreva de novo e posso mostrar como fazer.

Essa é a função que usa recursão em `cnctn`:

```
int* cnctn2v_r(int* v1, int sz1, int* v2, int sz2)
{
    int* v3 = (int*)malloc((sz1 + sz2) * sizeof(int));
    if (v3 == NULL) return NULL;
    cnctn(v1, v3, sz1);
    cnctn(v2, v3 + sz1, sz2);
    return v3;
}
```

E essa é a função recursiva:

```
void cnctn(int* from, int* to, int ix)
{
    *to = *from;
    if (ix == 1) return;
    cnctn(++from, ++to, --ix);
};
```

### o codigo completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// as duas funcoes
int* concatenarDoisVetores(int*, int, int*, int);
int* cnctn2v_i(int*, int, int*, int); // iterativa
int* cnctn2v_r(int*, int, int*, int); // recursiva

int show_v(int*, int, const char*);  // mostra o vetor

void cnctn(int*, int*, int);  // a funcao recursiva

int testa_funcao(
    int* (*)(int*, int, int*, int), int*, int, int*, int,
    const char*);

int main(void)
{   // os vetores
    int v1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int sz1  = sizeof(v1) / sizeof(v1[0]);
    show_v(v1, sz1, "\nVetor 1: ");
    int v2[] = {7, 8, 9};
    int sz2  = sizeof(v2) / sizeof(v2[0]);
    show_v(v2, sz2, "\nVetor 2: ");
    // e os testes
    testa_funcao(
        concatenarDoisVetores, v1, sz1, v2, sz2,
        "\n(iterativa 1) ");
    testa_funcao(
        cnctn2v_r, v1, sz1, v2, sz2, "\n(recursiva) ");
    testa_funcao(
        cnctn2v_i, v1, sz1, v2, sz2, "\n(iterativa 2) ");
    return 0;
}

int* concatenarDoisVetores(
    int* vetor1, int vetor1Posicoes, int* vetor2,
    int vetor2Posicoes)
{
    int* vetor3;
    int  vetor2Posicao = 0;

    vetor3 = (int*)malloc(
        (vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes) * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < vetor1Posicoes + vetor2Posicoes;
         i++)
    {
        if (i < vetor1Posicoes) { vetor3[i] = vetor1[i]; }
        else
        {
            vetor3[i] = vetor2[vetor2Posicao];
            vetor2Posicao++;
        }
    }
    return vetor3;
}

int* cnctn2v_i(int* v1, int sz1, int* v2, int sz2)
{
    int* v3 = (int*)malloc((sz1+sz2) * sizeof(int));
    if (v3 == NULL) return v3;
    int* p = v3;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz1; i++) *p++ = v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz2; i++) *p++ = v2[i];
    return v3;
}

int* cnctn2v_r(int* v1, int sz1, int* v2, int sz2)
{
    int* v3 = (int*)malloc((sz1 + sz2) * sizeof(int));
    if (v3 == NULL) return NULL;
    cnctn(v1, v3, sz1);
    cnctn(v2, v3 + sz1, sz2);
    return v3;
}

int show_v(int* V, int sz, const char* msg)
{
    if (V == NULL) return -1;
    if (sz <= 0) return 0;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("%d valor(es): [ ", sz);
    if (sz == 1)
    {
        printf("%d ]\n", V[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) printf("%i, ", V[i]);
    printf("%i ]\n", V[sz - 1]);
    return 0;
}

int testa_funcao(
    int* (*f)(int*, int, int*, int), int* v1, int sz1,
    int* v2, int sz2, const char* msg)
{
    int* v3 = f(v1, sz1, v2, sz2);
    show_v(v3, sz1 + sz2, msg);
    free(v3);
    return 0;
}

void cnctn(int* from, int* to, int ix)
{
    *to = *from;
    if (ix == 1) return;
    cnctn(++from, ++to, --ix);
};
```

Comment: E minha resposta foi considerada inútil. Preciso melhorar!

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito útil, me ajudou bastante. E marquei ela como "aceita". Onde que falou que ela foi inútil? Eu só não respondi aqui até este momento porque o site me diz que aqui é pra comentar só o que for relevante para o problema em questão. Já que não sei por onde comentar essa sua situação (ou, pelo, só agradecer), estou falando por aqui mesmo. Novamente, muito obrigado, me esclareceu muita coisa na sua resposta.

Comment: :D não se preocupe. Bom que a resposta serviu de algo. Eu tenho esses _seguidores_ aqui que marcam como inútil toda resposta que eu escreva. Eles devem ter critérios de qualidade muito mais apurados que o meu, ou apenas gostam de me zoar...